# Create a framework from existing iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I'm new to iOS development and I got this project and need to convert it to a framework so that I can simply add it into different projects. Can someone please help me with this.

I tried different tutorials, but all of them is to create one from new projects

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, however you need to ask concrete programming questions and not request general help.

Comment: Thank you @trojanfoe. But I don't have any heads up to continue with. I was thinking someone could help me with this

Comment: Not here, no. Only concrete programming questions can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to make a framework, or module, from a project, the first thing you’ll need to do is, if you don’t have one already, make an Xcode project workspace (File > Save as Workspace) . The next step is to add a new framework “project” to your workspace (that could’ve been why you saw some resources telling you to make a new project) with File > New Project and choosing Cocoa Touch framework.  When you add it, make sure you pick your workspace under both Add to and Group. Then you will need to migrate in the files that you wanted to be in this module — make sure to choose copy items if needed. 
Here’s an article with more specific details on the process if you need it:
https://medium.com/kinandcartacreated/modular-ios-splitting-a-workspace-into-modules-331293f1090